# How to pivot on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

I am trying to create a SQL Statement to pivot a variable number of rows (up to 5) into a single row.  A small subset of the data looks like this:

```
+--------------+--------+-------+-------+
|      ID      | ItemID | Style |  Qty  |
+--------------+--------+-------+-------+
| 00001-5A-2XL | F911-5 | F911  | 1.566 |
| 00001-5A-2XL | 233-5  | 233   | 0.236 |
| 00001-5A-3XL | F911-5 | F911  | 1.697 |
| 00001-5A-3XL | 233-5  | 233   | 0.237 |
| 00001-5A-4XL | F911-5 | F911  | 1.833 |
| 00001-5A-4XL | 233-5  | 233   | 0.239 |
| 00001-5A-L   | F911-5 | F911  | 1.307 |
| 00001-5A-L   | 233-5  | 233   | 0.234 |
+--------------+--------+-------+-------+
```

and I would like to pivot the data to look like the following:

```
+--------------+------+--------+-----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
|      ID      |  S1  | S1_Qty | S2  | S2_Qty | S3 | S3_Qty | S4 | S4_Qty | S5 | S5_Qty |
+--------------+------+--------+-----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
| 00001-5A-2XL | F911 | 1.566  | 233 | 0.236  |    |        |    |        |    |        |
| 00001-5A-3XL | F911 | 1.566  | 233 | 0.237  |    |        |    |        |    |        |
| 00001-5A-4XL | F911 | 1.566  | 233 | 0.239  |    |        |    |        |    |        |
| 00001-5A-L   | F911 | 1.566  | 233 | 0.234  |    |        |    |        |    |        |
+--------------+------+--------+-----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
```

I am a bit lost when it comes to pivoting, particularly when I want to pivot both the `Style` and the `Quantity` into my columns.  There my be up to 5 styles (rows) that need to be translated into up to 5 columns.

Any suggestions, pointers, etc would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is putting the same style into the same column a requirement?

Comment: No, in fact, its not desired, as I would like the highest quantity in the first column, then the next highest quantity in the second etc... down to the lowest quantity, up to 5 style/quantity pairs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few different ways that you can get the result depending on your needs.

It is not very clear if you need to use two different aggregates to get the result.  If you need to possibly `sum(qty)` and then use `max()` on the `style`, I would suggest using the aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result:

```
select id,
  max(case when ItemID = 'F911-5' then Style end) Style1,
  sum(case when ItemID = 'F911-5' then Qty else 0 end) Qty1,
  max(case when ItemID = '233-5' then Style end) Style2,
  sum(case when ItemID = '233-5' then Qty else 0 end) Qty2
from yourtable
group by id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e56d5/13). Then when you have new `ItemId` values you will just add new columns.

You can also use the PIVOT function, but since you need to PIVOT on two columns, I would first unpivot the `style` and `Qty` columns first.  This will convert your multiple columns of data into multiple rows, and you can get the result using the UNPIVOT function or CROSS APPLY - the basic syntax will be:

```
select id, 
  col = col+cast(seq as varchar(10)), value
from
(
  select id, itemid, style, qty,
    row_number() over(partition by id
                      order by qty desc) seq
  from yourtable
) src
cross apply
(
  select 'style', style union all
  select 'qty', cast(qty as varchar(10))
) c(col, value)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e56d5/20). This turns your data into multiple rows that can then be pivoted:

```
|           ID |    COL |   VALUE |
|--------------|--------|---------|
| 00001-5A-2XL | style1 |    F911 |
| 00001-5A-2XL |   qty1 | 1.56600 |
| 00001-5A-2XL | style2 |     233 |
| 00001-5A-2XL |   qty2 | 0.23600 |
| 00001-5A-3XL | style1 |    F911 |
```

Then you can apply the PIVOT function to get the final result:

```
select id, style1, qty1, style2, qty2
from
(
  select id, 
    col = col+cast(seq as varchar(10)), value
  from
  (
    select id, itemid, style, qty,
      row_number() over(partition by id
                        order by qty desc) seq
    from yourtable
  ) src
  cross apply
  (
    select 'style', style union all
    select 'qty', cast(qty as varchar(10))
  ) c(col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (style1, qty1, style2, qty2)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e56d5/17).  Finally if you have an unknown number of values, then you can use dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col+cast(seq as varchar(10)))
                    from 
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by id
                                                order by qty desc) seq
                      from yourtable
                    ) t
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'style', 1 union all
                      select 'qty', 2
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by col, so, seq
                    order by seq, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, ' + @cols + ' 
             from 
             (
                select id, 
                  col = col+cast(seq as varchar(10)), value
                from
                (
                  select id, itemid, style, qty,
                    row_number() over(partition by id
                                      order by qty desc) seq
                  from yourtable
                ) src
                cross apply
                (
                  select ''style'', style union all
                  select ''qty'', cast(qty as varchar(10))
                ) c(col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e56d5/19). These give a result:

```
|           ID | STYLE1 |    QTY1 | STYLE2 |    QTY2 |
|--------------|--------|---------|--------|---------|
| 00001-5A-2XL |   F911 | 1.56600 |    233 | 0.23600 |
| 00001-5A-3XL |   F911 | 1.69700 |    233 | 0.23700 |
| 00001-5A-4XL |   F911 | 1.83300 |    233 | 0.23900 |
|   00001-5A-L |   F911 | 1.30700 |    233 | 0.23400 |
```